# Internet Explorer crashes on startup

Tags: windows, crash, internet-explorer-7

I have 3 machines (all Dell GX520 running Windows XP SP3 with IE7) exhibiting the same problem - when launching IE, it crashes straightaway with a generic memory error with no specified module or further information.

I have tried the following to no avail:

- Reinstalled IE7
- Removed and installed IE7
- Ran IE7 with no extensions / addons disabled / deleted all external addons
- spyware check - found stuff, fixed, now clean
- AV - clean
- Installed / uninstalled IE updates

IE loads fine when not connected to the network. Firefox loads fine.

Any further suggestions or ideas are most welcome.

Comment: What virus scanner are you using?

Comment: Plus please have a look in the Event Viewer log, it might give us info on what the real error is

Comment: Event Log info : 
Type: Error
Source: Application Error
Eventid: 1000

Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 7.0.6000.16791, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0xf8ff54cb.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: Sophos is AV But have also ran a number of standalone scanners

Comment: Is this 64bit xp?  That address of 0xf8ff54cb isn't a user mode address for 32-bit xp.

Comment: Did you try to reset IE to factory default from Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset ... ?

Comment: Three different machines, same user? Occam's razor : change the user. :p

Comment: **"IE loads fine when not connected to the network."** - if you open IE while disconnected, then connect, does IE stay up and running or does it fall over again?

Answer (score 1):

Please restart your system in 'SAFE MODE' & try opening IE. If it works then something's interfering with IE in regular boot mode. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to IE8?

Here's [the download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=341C2AD5-8C3D-4347-8C03-08CDECD8852B&displaylang=nl)

Comment: Not an option - currently some of our corporate apps do not support IE8!

Comment: Just curious, IE8 compat mode doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment, but within 3-5 months we should be able to upgrade to it. Just doesn't resolve my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

When did you install IE7 in relation to XPSP3? if before, rollback the SP and put the SP on first, then IE7..

You can also use "process explorer" from sysinternals to analyse all modules loaded by iexplore.exe and pause the process right when you are connecting to the network, to show changes/stacks/network usage/etc. erroneous plugins (hidden stuff) and the version of the loaded modules. (compare with working workstation)